# Get request in controller isn't working and says that the http resource was not found

Tags: c#, json

I want to do a get request but if I fill in the id then it isn't working. it doesn't go in the function it says that no http resource was found that matches the request URI.

Below is my request

```
http://localhost:62662/api/Users/1
```

Below you find the controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    //[Authorize]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        AuthContext db = new AuthContext();
        var user = db.Users.Single(x => x.UserName == "BartBart");
        var gebruikerid = user.Id;
        //ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        return Ok(string.Format("id:{0}", gebruikerid));
        //return Ok(Order.CreateOrders());
    }

}
```

below is my webapiconfig class

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to remove the [Route] and [RoutePrefix] attribute? i think it is not needed here

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Include the `id` parameter in the route spec.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    //[Authorize]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        AuthContext db = new AuthContext();
        var user = db.Users.Single(x => x.UserName == "BartBart");
        var gebruikerid = user.Id;
        //ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        return Ok(string.Format("id:{0}", gebruikerid));
        //return Ok(Order.CreateOrders());
    }

}
```